# nginx server_name alias returning Not Found page

Tags: nginx

I have a server which was originally created in Laravel Forge. I am trying to add a second alias domain for the server. I have updated the server_name property in sites-available to include the new domain, restarted nginx and can see the change in sites-enabled. However, listing the site still just returns the nginx default not found page. Why would this be? Is there another setting I need to change to get a response?

```
server {
listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
server_name site.example.com site.other.com;
root /home/forge/site.example.com/public;
```

The config file is otherwise unchanged from the Forge [install default](https://forge.laravel.com/docs/1.0/sites/the-basics.html#default-nginx-template).

Comment: Does the new domain resolve to the IP address of that server?

Comment: Please add output of `nginx -T` to the question.